# Button.getMeasureWidth() returns bigger value than actual size. / Make very small buttons programatically

Tags: android, button, height, size, measurement

I got stuck with these problems :

1. I have a button . I want to make it (programatically) as small as I want ( e.g. width = 1, height = 1). I tried with setWidth(1)  and setHeight(1) but it doesn't work . I searched and I found something about small buttons. So i created my button like:

   ```
   Button b1 = new Button(mContext,null,android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
   b1.setMinimumHeight(0);

   b1.setMinimumWidth(0);

   b1.setWidth(1);

   b1.setHeight(1);
   ```

The buttons got smaller , but not small enough . They still seem to have a min size bigger than (0,0) . I could set at every size i wanted by using params, but I don't understand why it's not working without using params.Please give me a solution or just explain me why it's only working this way.

2. I need to make the text inside a button to fit the space. (i want the text to be as bigger as possible). I had to do a similar job for a textView . The solution I found was to do a binary search for the size of the font (initially i set the maxWidth, `textView.setMaxWidth(maxWidth))` and then use `textView.measure(MeasureSpec.Unspecified,MeasureSpec.Unspecified)` and use getHeightMeasurement to check if it fits the  maxHeight. This solution worked for the `TextView`, but not for the button.

That is because whatever i do , the `button.getHeightMeasurement()` returns  a bigger value than what i wanted ( this happens even when the text inside the button is "" and the font size is 0). So please help me. Ask me for pieces of code or clarification . It's very annoying.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.